# Can I migrate from Magento 1.9 to 2.0 when my site crashed?

Tags: data-migration

My site on Magento has crashed, then the next day my hosting company said that there was an error somewhere with coding so I'm thinking now is the time to move from Magento 1.9 to 2.0. 
I set up the new VPS and installed the Magento 2.0. Is it possible to migrate my data (especially my products) to the new version of my site has crashed and I have no access to the Magento admin?

Comment: yes possible ..means you have magento 1.9 admin not access?

Comment: yes.. can you give detail solution for my case?

Comment: without checking how can give to solution

Comment: so why did you say it possible... give me some advices, please?

Comment: Firstly welcome, as you site has crashed id try and see the reason why it crashed and if there is a possiblity of getting it back up and running once you have a working version magento do have a migration tool avaible which you will be able to use which will aid you in the upgrade process https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: thank you for all your responses! I contacted the support agents of LitExtension - an automated migration service about my case and the problem resolved, thanks god! For anyone who is in the same case with me, first they suggested me to send them my database dump then I bought all-in-one service. They set up and migrated my site to Magento 2 (from a to z) successfully. Highly recommend!